# Voronoi polygon strange result

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen

[image] I am using QGIS 2.18.21. The attribute table of my shapefile has 88 features but after creating the Voronoi, only 86 are in the attribute table and all the points are showing inside the Voronoi diagram.

Please, what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you use the Count points in polygon (weighted) tool?

Comment: Are there coincident points?

Comment: I used vonoroi polygon under geometry tools. They actually have the same latitude with another point but a different longitude

Comment: They are actually coincident point. I just checked it again.  So I guess the two coincident points are regarded as one.

Comment: The 3 southern most points shouldn't be in the same polygon, and, just to the right, there is a polygon without point. Either the green points are not the ones used to create the voronoi polygons, or there is a problem during the polygon creation

Comment: yes that is true and I just realized that these are not the coincident points. The coordinates of these 3 points in the same polygon are different. So what could be the problem now?

Comment: The green points are the ones used to create the voronoi polygon. I have tried twice again but still getting the same result. The coincident points are not any of the three points in the same polygon.

Comment: There were several bugs in the QGIS Voronoi code. Many were fixed in QGIS 3.2.2 (not backported to QGIS 2.18).  Could you try with QGIS 3.2.2?

Comment: Hello Havard, i finally downloaded QGIS 3.2.2 and created the voronoi polygon and it worked perfectly and separated the three points that were initially in the same polygon. I actually also have 3.0.0 but it didn`t work also. So I went ahead and downloaded QGIS 3.2.2 and it did. Thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: @HåvardTveite your comment looks like it could be turned into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

PolyGeo suggested that my comment should be turned into an answer:

There were several bugs in the QGIS Voronoi code. Many were fixed in QGIS 3.2.2 (not backported to QGIS 2.18).  According to a comment from user118372 on Aug 28, upgrading to 3.2.2 solved the experienced problems.